# Script# - How do I access the document's style sheet infomation?

Tags: script#

In Javascript I can access the page's stylesheet information with the following command

Example: document.styleSheets.length

However in Script# I am unable to make the same call (or similiar), i.e. there is no property for stylesheet under Document.

Q: How can I access the document's stylesheet information in Script Sharp ?

Thanks in advance

- Rory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean you don't see StyleSheets come up in the intellisense list after you type 'Document.' ? That doesn't mean you can't get it to work since Script# is just there to emit JavaScript.

Unless you want to go to the work of adding it to Script# yourself (on gitHub), you will probably need to add the script using Script.Literal.

Comment: Thanks Jamasuss, correct, StyleSheets does not come up on the intellisense. Just checking was there another option besides using Script.Literal.

Answer (score 1):

I would avoid using Script.Literal. You'll end up with a bunch of unmaintainable code. The whole point you most likely are using Script# is to have strong typing and to make your code easy to refactor and maintain. Putting magic strings in Script.Literal goes against our principle to keep the code easy to maintain. If something isn't supported in script# intrinsic libraries then as others have suggested you could push to github. You also have the option of just extending an existing class or making your own.

In your case just create a couple new Script# classes. The key is to use the Imported Attribute.

```
[Imported]//keeps us from defining a javascript class in our emitted js library.
[ScriptName("document")]
public static class Html5Document
{

    public static StyleSheet[] StyleSheets//becomes styleSheets when emitted.
    {
        get 
        {
            return null;
        }
        set
        {
        }
    }
}

[Imported]
public static class StyleSheet
{

   //Add whatever property and methods you will need.
}
```

Now in your script# code you can write:

```
Html5Document.StyleSheets.Length();//c#
```

Your emitted javascript code will be.

```
document.styleSheets.length;//javascript
```